# BeautifulSoup.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'features' (when importing a custom BeautifulSoup wrapper function)

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

#### Problem

I had been using this wrapper function with no issues.

```
def make_soup(response):
        return BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

response = requests.get('https://www.webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone')

soup = make_soup(response) # No Error
```

However, after upgrading to python 3.11 from 3.8, when importing the function and trying to use it, I get the following error:

```
from util import make_soup
response = requests.get('https://www.webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone')

make_soup(response) # Error
```

```
TypeError: BeautifulSoup.__init__() got multiple 
values for argument 'features'
```

#### Attempted fix: Passing "features" as a keyword argument

I tried passing `lxml` as a keyword argument instead:

```
def make_soup(response):
    return bs(response.text, features='lxml')
```

Initially, this appeared to fix the issue, as the function ran fine when imported.

However, I noticed that often the returned BeautifulSoup object was missing large parts of the HTML, that were **not** missing if I executed the same code without importing it.

Here's one more extreme example

```
from util import make_soup

session = requests.Session()
response = session.get('https://www.deviantart.com/') # One of the many sites I tested this on

soup = bs(response.text, 'lxml')
soup_from_imported_func = make_soup(response)

num_divs = lambda soup: len(soup.find_all('div'))

print(num_divs(soup))
print(num_divs(soup_from_imported_func))
```

These printed values should be equal, but they're not.

```
0
1120
```

If I print the broken soup this is all I get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

I have tried using a different parser (`html.parser` and `html5lib`) but the issue persists.

#### Conclusion

As a temporary solution I can reluctantly repeat the contents of the make_soup function

However I would like to understand why this is happening, in case it generates more problems in the future.

Comment: try with `if __name__ == "__main__"`

Comment: thank you, but I have tried that and the error is the same

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/1969912 try different parser than lxml for now

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I experience the same problem if using html.parser or html5lib